# Bootstrap Table from Model

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap, sqlite

I have a table that I am trying to convert from static, mock data into real, live SQLite3 data. I am hoping to display my SQLite3 table within my HTML code including all three of my columns (Question | Answer | Pub_Date) and then display the values in the table.

My current code (below) adds the list of questions in, but it is adding them in as values from left to right rather than up and down (screenshot below). What would I need to adjust to get my simple table shown rather than the fake data?

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr style="font-family: Graphik Black; font-size: 14px">
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="font-family: Graphik; font-size: 12px">
      <th scope="row" class="container">1</th>
        {% for question in latest_question_list %}
            <td><li style="font-weight: 500;"><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li></td>
        {% endfor %}
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm badge-pill" style="font-size: 11px; width:60px" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="font-family: Graphik; font-size: 12px"> 
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm badge-pill" style="font-size: 11px; width:60px" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="font-family: Graphik; font-size: 12px">
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm badge-pill" style="font-size: 11px; width:60px"data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Desired table
[image]

Comment: What does your answer data structure look like?

Comment: My Answer data is just a simple free text field.... As you can see with the sample data, questions can be answered twice and receive different answers each time

Comment: Yes, that is neccessary to know.  It should be in the view, passed as a context variable.

Comment: Your example does not show that a question can be answered twice. This makes sharing of your data model even more important.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
   <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr style="font-family: Graphik Black; font-size: 14px">
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">First</th>
          <th scope="col">Last</th>
          <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <tr style="font-family: Graphik; font-size: 12px">
          <td><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li></td>
          <td>{{ question.answer }}</td>
          <td>{{ question.pub_date }}</td>
          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm badge-pill" style="font-size: 11px; width:60px" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new">Edit</button></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
```